# Why do the objects imported to libGDX look white?

Tags: materials, export

I have made a simple tree in Blender, which includes materials; However, when I import the objects [libGDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibGDX), they don't have their materials. In Blender it seems fine.

Is there a way to get the materials transferred over?

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify? I can't understand what your question is.

Comment: sorry, i have just sign up. Why doesnt tree seem colorly, it seem in blender with green and brown colors. When i export it as object and include the object to libgdx , it seem like in picture. how can i make it colorly in libgdx

Comment: Oh... I guess either the exporter or the importer doesn't support materials at all _or_ Blender materials are somehow not compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, i have to find some why the objects with orginal seeming.

Comment: BTW is there a default importer to be used in libGDX or have you written your own?

Comment: Which format do you use to transfer it to libgdx? Not sure but the tutorials I found so far always include textures: http://codebin.co.uk/blog/using-blender-3d-models-in-libgdx/ and http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/01/19/3D-models-and-animation-from-Blender-to-LibGDX.aspx

Comment: Was there a `.mtl` file along with the exported obj?

Comment: When i try to export , blender creates .obj and .mtl files, but unfourtanelty i seem like this. Thank you all. By the way i have use .obj and .mtl formats.

Comment: The is importer in libgdx, it's model loader class.

Comment: stacker, i was found them before. The objects that i include to blender before export them as .obj , its format is 3ds. And there is no texture

Answer (score 1):

Had you checked in blender's cycles render? If not, you probably not handle the material correctly.

In my case, this defection comes from the material arrangement as a result of my unfamiliar with blender. I think it's the material should loaded by gdx until i compared the results from the same java code with the obj file used by xoppa's tutorial. see the tutorial:

https://xoppa.github.io/blog/loading-models-using-libgdx/

The ship's material is showing.

You'd better check it.

Another way to check the material is exported correctly is open and search your obj or g3dj files.

In obj file's 'f' section, the vertex's format is position/uv/norm, see

https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/docs/brief-obj-file-format.html
My case is "3//0.3, ...", so there the problem is picture not mapped to vertex.

If you open the g3dj file, the lack of UV mapping will makes fbx-conv converting empty UV mapping, like:

```
    {
        "version": [  0,   1], 
        "id": "", 
        "meshes": [
            {
                "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL"], 
                "vertices": [ some-6-dimesional-vectors ...
```

This vertices lacking UV data. The "attributes" should actually 3 attribures:

```
    ["POSITION", "NORMAL", "TEXCOORD0"]
```

And the vertices should be 8 elements.

To unwrap and uv mapping, see blender manual:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#unwrap

Hope this will be helpful although years latter.